# Why add 0.5 to a z-score?

Tags: statistics

Can anyone explain when should I add 0.5 to the z-score?

Comment: Could you give some context?  It's going to be hard to answer your question without more information.

Comment: example Pr(z <= 1.35) = 0.5 + Pr(0 <= Z <= 1.35) = 0.5 + 0.4115

Comment: and why is Pr(0 <= z <= 1.5) = 0.4332 without adding 0.5?

Comment: Well, if the distribution is symmetric and continuous then $Pr(z\leq 0)=0.5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example you give in your comment above, I think what's being used is that $P(z\lt 0)=0.5$ (and $P(z\gt 0)=0.5$, too), so that $P(z\le 1.35)=P((z\lt0)\text{ or }(0\le z\le 1.35))=0.5+P(0\le z\le 1.35)$.

Comment: well, can you further elaborate?

Comment: $z$-scores are typically on datasets that are expected to be normally distributed and the $z$-score is the number of standard deviations from the mean.  So, the probability of being below (or above) the mean should be 0.5.

Comment: I think Isaac has it right.  Some statistics tables give the $z$ score probability corresponding to $P(0 \leq Z \leq z)$, while some give it for $P(Z \leq z)$.  I'm guessing OP is looking at one of the former.  (See, for example, http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution-table.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your problem involves binomial probabilities, and you wish to use the normal approximation to the binomial, you would add .5 to the z formula (not the score) as a continuity correction factor.